# Can Paragraph Tags in a RichTextBox be Saved or Loaded?

Tags: wpf, xaml, richtextbox

Within a `RichTextBox`, I use the paragraph `Tag` for information, such as paragraph topic, e.g.,

```
string[] np = new string[]
{
    "B-CC:", "B-HPI:", "B-ROS:", "B-PMH:", "B-PSH:"
};

RichTextControl.Document.Blocks.Clear();
foreach (var s in np)
{
    var p = new Paragraph();
    p.Tag = s;
    RichTextControl.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
}
```

Can the information within the Tag be saved and later recalled from a `MemoryStream`?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `XamlWrite.Save` method to serialize the `RichTextBox`, including the `Paragraph`s and the `Tag` property values:

```
//serialize:
string xaml = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(RichTextControl);
//de-serialize:
RichTextBox rtb = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as RichTextBox;
foreach(var p in rtb.Document.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>())
{
    if(p.Tag != null)
    {
        string tag = p.Tag.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm persisting the content (text and images) in a byte[] of a network database. Can the string xaml then be encoded as a byte[] ? Thanks.